# Returning Bool from one class to another in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, model-view-controller, swift

I have here a piece of code, and i can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work.

The viewController is supposed to check whether a switch is turned on or off.

```
class ViewControllerFirst: UIViewController {  


@IBAction func friendFunc(){
    if friendSwitch.on{
        friendOn = true
    }   else    {
        friendOn = false
    }
}

func returnFriend() -> Bool{
    return friendOn
    }
}
```

And if the switch is turned on, an Array should be added to tempArray.

```
import Foundation

struct DareBook {

let fview = ViewControllerFirst()
let dareArrayFriend = [""]

func randomDare() -> String{

    var tempArray = [""]
    if  ViewControllerFirst().returnFriend() == true{
        tempArray += dareArrayFriend
    }  
    var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(tempArray.count)
    var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return tempArray[randomNumber]
    }
}
```

i'm not getting any errormessages when i build, but it singles out this line:

```
    func returnFriend() -> Bool{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new view controller when you call the function. That is probably not what you want.

```
func randomDare() -> String{

    var tempArray = [""]
    // if  ViewControllerFirst().returnFriend() == true{ <--- this line can't be right
    if  fview.returnFriend() == true{
        tempArray += dareArrayFriend
    }  
    var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(tempArray.count)
    var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return tempArray[randomNumber]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are instantiating a new view controller every time you check that boolean, (`ViewControllerFirst()` seems like it should be `fview` at the least and I don't think that fview is the actual ViewController that you want) so it seems to me that it would always be false.